# Biblatex: Print bibliography for a single entry within an enumeration

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I have the following LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{firstpaper}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{secondpaper}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{enumpapers}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{Gyro2012,
        author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
        title = {1st paper with a very loooooooooooong title, so it spans multiple rows},
    }
    @misc{Gyro2013,
        author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
        title = {2nd paper},
    }
    @misc{Stark2012,
        author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
        title = {3rd paper},
    }
    @misc{Stark2013,
        author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
        title = {4th paper},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\addtocategory{firstpaper}{Gyro2012}
\addtocategory{secondpaper}{Gyro2013}
\addtocategory{enumpapers}{Gyro2012,Gyro2013}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \printbibliography[heading=none,category=firstpaper]
    \setcounter{enumi}{9} % Two digits to test alignment
    \item \printbibliography[heading=none,category=secondpaper]
\end{enumerate}

\printbibliography[notcategory=enumpapers]

\end{document}
```

that results in the following output

[image: LaTeX output]

My question is: How can I achieve the same output without declaring an own category for each paper that appears in the enumeration? In other words: I am looking for something similar to the \fullcite command that also prints the [1] and so on (preferred solution).

I guess there is also a solution using \defbibenvironment but then my follow-up question is: How can I rearrange the bibliography entries to a specific order that only holds for the enumeration.

Furthermore, I am only looking for solution that are compatible with biblatex.

Comment: What about `\cite{foo}\fullcite{foo}\addtocategory{enumpapers}{foo}` (you could of course put that into a macro as well).

Comment: `\cite{foo}\fullcite{foo}...` would misalign the first item, because the "span" would start below the "[1]" (and not below "Gyro Gearloose").

Answer (score 4):

Instead of defining a separate category for each entry, we can dynamically create a `bibcheck`, we do retain the `enumpapers` category though, as it is very convenient.

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{enumpapers}
```

Our new command `\enumcite` adds the key to `enumpapers`, creates a bibcheck for the entry key and prints the bibliography

```
\newcommand{\enumcite}[1]{%
  \addtocategory{enumpapers}{#1}%
  \defbibcheck{key#1}{
    \iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{#1}
      {}
      {\skipentry}}%
  \printbibliography[heading=none,check=key#1]%
}
```

We can use `\enumcite` like this

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \enumcite{Gyro2012}
    \setcounter{enumi}{9} % Two digits to test alignment
    \item \enumcite{Gyro2013}
\end{enumerate}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Gyro2012,
  author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
  title = {1st paper with a very loooooooooooong title, so it spans multiple rows},
}
@misc{Gyro2013,
  author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
  title = {2nd paper},
}
@misc{Stark2012,
  author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
  title = {3rd paper},
}
@misc{Stark2013,
  author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
  title = {4th paper},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{enumpapers}

\newcommand{\enumcite}[1]{%
  \addtocategory{enumpapers}{#1}%
  \defbibcheck{key#1}{
    \iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{#1}
      {}
      {\skipentry}}%
  \printbibliography[heading=none,check=key#1]%
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \enumcite{Gyro2012}
    \setcounter{enumi}{9} % Two digits to test alignment
    \item \enumcite{Gyro2013}
\end{enumerate}

\printbibliography[notcategory=enumpapers]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking for such a solution at the moment. Is your "old" proposal still valid/recommended?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It still works in the MWE as you can easily check. If it is the "best" solution for what you are trying to do depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks. My question was not super clear, sorry. I meant, if there is by now a more "off the shelf" feature. But I will use the code as is then.

Answer (score 2):

More a workaround than a proper solution but you can replace

```
\item \printbibliography[heading=none,category=firstpaper]
```

by something like:

```
\item \cite{Gyro2012}\quad \fullcite{Gyro2012}
```

The `\cite` part generates the brackets (`[1]`) and `\quad` is necessary to have the correct horizontal spacing between brackets and citation.

The workaround could be easily simplified by the creation of a command:

```
\newcommand{\enumcite}[1]{\cite{#1}\quad \fullcite{#1}}
\enumcite{Gyro2012}
```

This way you don't have to create a category for each paper. The (possible) problem is that you cite twice the same paper.

---

**MWE** (produces the same output than yours):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{firstpaper}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{secondpaper}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{enumpapers}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{Gyro2012,
        author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
        title = {1st paper with a very loooooooooooong title, so it spans multiple rows},
    }
    @misc{Gyro2013,
        author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
        title = {2nd paper},
    }
    @misc{Stark2012,
        author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
        title = {3rd paper},
    }
    @misc{Stark2013,
        author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
        title = {4th paper},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}


\newcommand{\enumcite}[1]{\cite{#1}\quad \fullcite{#1}}

\addtocategory{enumpapers}{Gyro2012,Gyro2013}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \enumcite{Gyro2012}
    \setcounter{enumi}{9} % Two digits to test alignment
    \item \enumcite{Gyro2013}
\end{enumerate}

\printbibliography[notcategory=enumpapers]

\end{document}
```